Can't install recent version of flutter_secure_storage on Flutter
I was having an issue with the flutter_secure_storage. It is giving me the following error when I try to use it:

Exception has occurred. MissingPluginException
(MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method write on
channel plugins.it_nomads.com/flutter_secure_storage))

After searching on the web and testing a bunch of clean commands, I noticed Flutter installed the version ^4.2.1, but on pub.dev the lastest version is 9.2.2, so I guess that is the reason I am receiving the implementation not found error. The installed version is that old! When I try to manually set the version to ^9.2.2 on the pubspec.yaml file, I get build failed error.
This is the output of flutter pub outdated:
Showing outdated packages.
[*] indicates versions that are not the latest available.

Package Name                  Current     Upgradable  Resolvable  Latest   

direct dependencies:
async                         *2.11.0     *2.11.0     *2.11.0     2.12.0   
flutter_secure_storage        *4.2.1      *4.2.1      *4.2.1      9.2.2    
intl                          *0.19.0     *0.19.0     *0.19.0     0.20.1   
path                          *1.9.0      *1.9.0      *1.9.0      1.9.1    

dev_dependencies:
json_serializable             *6.9.0      *6.9.0      *6.9.0      6.9.2    

transitive dependencies:     
archive                       *3.6.1      *3.6.1      *3.6.1      4.0.2    
characters                    *1.3.0      *1.3.0      *1.3.0      1.4.0    
clock                         *1.1.1      *1.1.1      *1.1.1      1.1.2    
collection                    *1.19.0     *1.19.0     *1.19.0     1.19.1   
device_info_plus              *10.1.2     *10.1.2     *10.1.2     11.2.0   
image                         *4.3.0      *4.3.0      *4.3.0      4.5.2
js                            *0.6.7      0.7.1       0.7.1       0.7.1
material_color_utilities      *0.11.1     *0.11.1     *0.11.1     0.12.0
meta                          *1.15.0     *1.15.0     *1.15.0     1.16.0
source_span                   *1.10.0     *1.10.0     *1.10.0     1.10.1
stack_trace                   *1.12.0     *1.12.0     *1.12.0     1.12.1
stream_channel                *2.1.2      *2.1.2      *2.1.2      2.1.3
string_scanner                *1.3.0      *1.3.0      *1.3.0      1.4.1
term_glyph                    *1.2.1      *1.2.1      *1.2.1      1.2.2
win32_registry                *1.1.5      *1.1.5      *1.1.5      2.0.1

transitive dev_dependencies:
_fe_analyzer_shared           *76.0.0     *76.0.0     *76.0.0     78.0.0
analyzer                      *6.11.0     *6.11.0     *6.11.0     7.1.0
analyzer_plugin               *0.11.3     *0.11.3     *0.11.3     0.12.0
boolean_selector              *2.1.1      *2.1.1      *2.1.1      2.1.2
dart_style                    *2.3.7      *2.3.7      *2.3.7      3.0.1
fake_async                    *1.3.1      *1.3.1      *1.3.1      1.3.2
leak_tracker                  *10.0.7     *10.0.7     *10.0.7     10.0.8
leak_tracker_flutter_testing  *3.0.8      *3.0.8      *3.0.8      3.0.9
matcher                       *0.12.16+1  *0.12.16+1  *0.12.16+1  0.12.17
source_gen                    *1.5.0      *1.5.0      *1.5.0      2.0.0
test_api                      *0.7.3      *0.7.3      *0.7.3      0.7.4
vm_service                    *14.3.0     *14.3.0     *14.3.0     15.0.0

1 upgradable dependency is locked (in pubspec.lock) to an older version.
To update it, use `flutter pub upgrade`.

I have tried the following commands with no success:
flutter pub cache clean
flutter clean
flutter upgrade
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions 

Can you help me?

Is fluter clean a typo?   (fluter vs flutter)

@SecretAgentMan Yes, it is a typo. I will correct. Thank you.

This error usually occurs when a package is added while the Flutter application is running on the emulator. Hot reload or hot restart does not allow the package to be added to the application, so the application must be completely terminated and restarted.
The solution steps I will suggest

Completely terminate and restart the application


Before restart the app , do this two steps flutter clean -> flutter pub get


https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage make sure you are doing right the installation of package


I already tried those. It don't work. I guess it's a problem with the package. I'll look for alternatives.

the package is not have problem , i am using it at project right now , its well working
